# How can I use Moq here?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, asp.net-core-webapi

My WEB API project is using a `Generic` Repository that implements an interface like this:

```
public interface IGenericEFRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> Get();
    Task<TEntity> Get(int id);
}

public class GenericEFRepository<TEntity> : IGenericEFRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    private SqlDbContext _db;
    public GenericEFRepository(SqlDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> Get()
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(_db.Set<TEntity>());
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> Get(int id)
    {
        var entity = await Task.FromResult(_db.Set<TEntity>().Find(new object[] { id }));

        if (entity != null && includeRelatedEntities)
        {
            //Some Code
        }
        return entity;
    }
}
```

Well now I want to test this service. for this I have used the following code:

```
public class CustomerControllerTest
{
    CustomerController _controller;
    ICustomerProvider _provider;
    ICustomerInquiryMockRepository _repo;

    public CustomerControllerTest()
    {
        _repo = new CustomerInquiryMockRepository();
        _provider = new CustomerProvider(_repo);
        _controller = new CustomerController(_provider);
    }

     [Fact]
    public async Task Get_WhenCalled_ReturnsOkResult()
    {
        // Act
        var okResult = await _controller.Get();

        // Assert
        Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(okResult);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetById_UnknownCustomerIdPassed_ReturnsNotFoundResult()
    {
        // Act
        var notFoundResult = await _controller.Get(4);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsType<NotFoundResult>(notFoundResult);
    }
}
```

Which my tests are working fine by creating a fake non-generic service manually with mock data (In-Memory) like below, instead of using my real generic interface and it's implementation that uses my database as data-source:

```
public interface ICustomerInquiryMockRepository
{
    Task<IEnumerable<CustomerDTO>> GetCustomers();
    Task<CustomerDTO> GetCustomer(int customerId);
}
```

And it's implementation:

```
public class CustomerInquiryMockRepository : ICustomerInquiryMockRepository
{       
    public async Task<IEnumerable<CustomerDTO>> GetCustomers()
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(MockData.Current.Customers);
    }

    public async Task<CustomerDTO> GetCustomer(int CustomerId)
    {
        var Customer = await Task.FromResult(MockData.Current.Customers.FirstOrDefault(p => p.CustomerID.Equals(CustomerId)));

        if (includeTransactions && Customer != null)
        {
            Customer.Transactions = MockData.Current.Transactions.Where(b => b.CustomerId.Equals(CustomerId)).ToList();
        }

        return Customer;
    }
}
```

And the `MockData.Current.Customers` is just a simple fake (In-Memory) List of Customers. Long story short, the above tests are working fine, however I am feeling I have repeated my self a lot and so I have decided to use Moq library instead of creating fake service manually. For this purpose I have used Moq like this:

```
public class CustomerControllerTest
{
    CustomerController _controller;
    ICustomerProvider _provider;
    //ICustomerInquiryMockRepository _repo;
    Mock<ICustomerInquiryMockRepository> mockUserRepo;


    public CustomerControllerTest()
    {
        mockUserRepo = new Mock<ICustomerInquiryMockRepository>();
        //_repo = new CustomerInquiryMockRepository();
        _provider = new CustomerProvider(mockUserRepo.Object);
        _controller = new CustomerController(_provider);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Get_WhenCalled_ReturnsOkResult()
    {
        mockUserRepo.Setup(m => m.GetCustomers())
            .Returns(Task.FromResult(MockData.Current.Customers.AsEnumerable()));
        // Act
        var okResult = await _controller.Get();

        // Assert
        Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(okResult);
    }


    [Fact]
    public async Task GetById_UnknownCustomerIdPassed_ReturnsNotFoundResult()
    {
        //Arrange
        I don't know how can I use Moq here and in the other parts of my tests

        // Act
        var notFoundResult = await _controller.Get(4);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsType<NotFoundResult>(notFoundResult);
    }
```

Now my question is the `Mock` is working fine when I use it for Mocking the `GetCustomers` method because I simply paste the code from `GetCustomers` method in the `CustomerInquiryMockRepository` in the `Returns` method of the `Mock` object. However I don't really have any idea how can I use Mock for my other methods inside this Repository. Should I replace anything that I have in the `Return` method?

Comment: Just make the mocked repository return the same result that the real repository would return if the object wasn't found. Whether that's an exception, or a null result, or something else depends on how the repository was implemented. Seems like you're overthinking this.

Comment: @mason Would you please show me how can I achieve to what you stated by proving an answer?

Comment: @mason If I have to use the implemented real repository, then I have to deal with my real database that it is not the purpose of the Moq nor unit tests. OK?

Comment: No, I didn't say to use the real repository. You need to however mock what the real repository is doing. So if your real repository would return `null` when passed a customer ID that isn't in the system, then your mock one should as well.

Comment: @mason Please provide an answer, if it is possible for you. I need more clarification on this please.

Answer (score 1):

You can mock out your repository like so:

```
var mockUserRepo = new Mock<ICustomerInquiryMockRepository>();
mockUserRepo.Setup(x => x.GetCustomers())
            .Returns(Task.FromResult(MockData.Current.Customers.AsEnumerable());
mockUserRepo.Setup(x => x.GetCustomer(It.IsAny<int>()))
            .Returns(res => Task.FromResult(MockData.Current.Customers.ElementAt(res));
```

If you want to mock out specific values for `GetCustomer`, you can do:

```
mockUserRepo.Setup(x => x.GetCustomer(It.Is<int>(y => y == 4)))
            .Returns(res => Task.FromResult(/* error value here */));
```

I think the key here is to use `It.Is` or `It.IsAny` based on how you want to mock out the object. Generally, you also want to mock out interfaces that are used in production code, instead of having production code depend on something with `Mock` or `Test` in the name. I would recommend against taking a production code dependency on something named `ICustomerInquiryMockRepository`, if that is indeed what you're doing and not just part of the MCVE you've provided.

Tests usually use mocking to test the workflow of an application at a high level, so you would usually want to mock out your services level, call a controller, and verify that the services were called as expected. For example:

```
// Production class sample
class ProductionController
{
  public ProductionController(IService1 service1, IService2 service2) { }

  public void ControllerMethod()
  {
    var service1Result = service1.Method();
    service2.Method(service1Result);
  }
}

// Test sample
// arrange
var expectedResult = new Service1Result();
var service1 = Mock.Of<IService1>(x => x.Method() == expectedResult);
var service2 = Mock.Of<IService2>(x => x.Method(It.Is<Service1Result>(y => y == expectedResult)));
var controller = new ProductionController(service1, service2);

// act
controller.ControllerMethod();

// assert
Mock.Get(service1).Verify(x => x.Method(), Times.Once);
Mock.Get(service2).Verify(x => x.Method(expectedResult), Times.Once);
```

As you can see from the example, you aren't checking the business logic of either of the services, you're just validating that the methods were called with the expected data. The test is built around verification of methods being *called*, not any particular branching logic.

---

Also, unrelated to your question, Moq also has a cool syntax you can use for simple mock setups:

```
var repo = Mock.Of<ICustomerInquiryMockRepository>(x => 
    x.GetCustomers() == Task.FromResult(MockData.Current.Customers.AsEnumerable()));
```

You can use `Mock.Get(repo)` if you need to do additional setup on the repository. It's definitely worth checking out, I find it much nicer to read.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And what about this part `if (includeTransactions && Customer != null)
        {
            Customer.Transactions = MockData.Current.Transactions.Where(b => b.CustomerId.Equals(CustomerId)).ToList();
        }` of `GetCustomer` method?

Comment: Mocking is more about testing interactions than testing actual logic. You would want to have a unit test that covers the concrete implementation of your repository. From your `CustomerControllerTest` you should mock the expected result from the expected input, and treat the repository as a black box that "just works". (Separate) Integration tests can help test the entire workflow.

Comment: Thumbs up, taught me syntax Mock.Of
He is absolutely right about the intention of mocking. It's only to ensure your program flow & business interactions are set up properly & break the build if someone breaks the intended flow. If you need to test transactional data then subsequently you could implement some integration tests.

Comment: @E.Moffat What thing that you said, is the usage of fake service is correct? I have tested the workflow with that? What about my tests without mocking?

Comment: If by "fake service" you mean `MockData`, that's perfectly fine. I'll update my answer to describe how workflow tests usually look.

Comment: @E.Moffat By "fake service" I mean `CustomerInquiryMockRepository`.

Comment: @E.Moffat OK. Looking forward to your update please.

Comment: @J.P sorry got pulled into a meeting, example has been added. re: fake service - you should either mock ICustomerInquiryMockRepository or have a fake service, it doesn't make sense to have both. What I was saying is that your production code shouldn't reference code that's used explicitly for testing, the dependency should point the other way (test code depends references production code)

Comment: @E.Moffat I mean if I don't use Moq library my current code that I have posted in my question is correct? Didn't I repeat anything?

Comment: @E.Moffat Also please let me know, if I have several methods that each one test different behavior should I repeat this code for each method? `mockUserRepo.Setup(x => x.GetCustomer(It.IsAny<int>()))
            .Returns(res => Task.FromResult(MockData.Current.Customers.ElementAt(res));` Or I can configure it once and then reuse it whit different parameters?

Comment: @E.Moffat For example based on your suggestion I have repeat the above code in this method `GetById_UnknownCustomerIdPassed_ReturnsNotFoundResult` and this one `GetById_ExistingCustomerIdPassed_ReturnsOkResult()`. Where can I refactor it so I just configure it once for both methods?

Comment: You can configure it once in a setup method for the test. I think in XUnit you do this via the constructor. See [examples here](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context.html).